# Clear cache on view at a set date from a node field value?

Tags: views, caching, nodes

What would be the best approach to clear the drupal cache on the exact date and time that a node Date field is set to? It's easy enough to do it on node save, but if the node is to be included in views at the specific time that a date field is set to, then I would need someway to set the cache to be cleared at specific times corresponding to date field values on nodes?

Comment: And how are you scheduling publication in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

If the node is scheduled to be published in the future then presumably the node will also be saved at that time, to update its status. So the cache can be cleared on node save at that point.

Comment: Yeah sorry, should have pointed out that it is a view that checks if a date field is "field_publish_date >= now", so somehow I need to schedule a cache clear based on this value, this could be scheduled on node save I guess, but how to schedule?

Comment: @lasse please add this to your question, then, and note that it's not about changing value of node status but about views.

Comment: Updated the question.